# Made my user disappear

Tags: uninstall, zsh, user-profile

Recent I installed zsh and made it my default shell, but then I wanted the old one back and decided to uninstall using `command sudo apt-get --purge remove zsh`.

When I restarted my computer my user had dissapeared and I had to create a new one. Is there any way to restore my old user? I have a lot of important stuff there.

Comment: Purging ZSH should not delete the user. You have backups, right? If the data was important for you then you must have kept backups of it. Restore the data from backups

Comment: ... it could however have prevented you from *logging in as* that user - since they'd no longer have a valid login shell

Comment: @Someone I checked and I still have the user, but on the login screen it doesn't show

Comment: @steeldriver is there any way to restore that shell?

Comment: `sudo apt install zsh`

Comment: ... or you could change the user's old shell from the new user account: `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash oldusername`

Comment: @steeldriver I did those commands but after I restarted the computer the only user listed was the new one. I had to click in "not listed" an manually type my old username.

Comment: @steeldriver When I type `echo $0` on terminal it returns `bash`  and when I type `echo $SHELL` it returns `/bin/bash` , but still can't see the user on login.

Comment: OK sounds like that's not the problem then. Can you see the old user with `getent passwd oldusername`? Is their home directory still there (`ls /home`)? Are you able to login to a non-GUI session on one of the ttys?

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, I can see. It returns `/home/matheus:/bin/bash`. All the directories in matheus(oldusername) are okay. The only thing is that after restart my pc the only account that appears in the new one. Maybe if I delet the new username it will appear the old one when I restart?

Comment: But I'm a bit worried that if i delet new username and restart my pc it will go directly to a screen asking no create a new account

Comment: I'm logged in with the old username now, and when I go in configurations > users , the only user that appears is the new one